# File modify date is not updated in Finder file properties

Tags: finder, filesystem, textedit, macos

I have a video capture of a strange behavior:

File prior to editing:

[image: pre]

Edited at 5:15PM using TextEdit

In Finder I see the file with strange rename, and Modified date value is not updated, nor does the length (at least a few bytes should have been added).

[image: post]

What is the cause of this behavior?

Unfortunately, since I only have a video capture and the issue does not reproduce, I don't know if the file changed back to its normal `txt` form. But it does not seem to change for as long as the video run.

Sorry for the ambiguity, I'm working on getting a more accurate reproduction.

Comment: Important to mention, this is OSX 10.11 Developers Beta

Answer (score 1):

The strange edited file name is due to it currently saving a temporary file. Did you quit TextEdit after you edited the file?

Comment: I did quit it. Though it makes sense the OS could take its time to write to the file under some circumstances. I guess..